# Calling a method present in Viewmodel from OnNavigate of Page using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have to do some operations in OnNavigation of page. But I want to do all those operations in ViewModel.cs. For that I just want to call that method in ViewModel.cs from OnNavigation of Page.
I am not getting how to do that. I am creating Viewmodel.cs object in particular View,

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <obj:ViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
```

How to do this using Events and Delegates? and if there is some other way, then what is it.

Comment: try to use a wpf behavior or some trigger for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code behind you can get the reference of the viewmodel:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
    vm.NameOfYourMethod();
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: you should avoid to access a viewmodel from the code behind, it is more advisable to use a wpf behavior in this case.